# action script 2 use local variables inside anonymous function

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, anonymous-function

I'm new to action script 2.0, what I want is to use the local variables inside the anonymous function

```
var count = 0;
var evtObject = new Object();
Key.addListener(evtObject);
evtObject.onkeypress = function()
{
  if(Key.UP == Key.getCode())
  {
    // here i want to use the count value., count++;
    trace(count);
  }
}
```

Inside the if block i want to use the count value. Even though knowing that it wont work, I used it in the anonymous function of onkeypress, it obviously showed me **undefined**. Kindly help me to go through this.

Comment: _"I'm new to action script 2.0"_ start investing time with **ActionScript 3.0** and also it will prepare you for other C-like languages (eg: Java, C#, Swift etc)... Anyway : What is `if(Key.UP == Key.getCode())` trying to achieve? `Key.UP` is when a key **stops being pressed** (released) so what `Key.getCode()` could it be ever be **Equal To**? Are you looking for the "up" arrow key?

Answer (score 1):

Here i have given simple example of usage of local variable into function Please refer this Code..

```
 package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class keylister 
{
    var alldisplay:MovieClip;
    var left:uint = 37;
    var up:uint = 38;
    var right:uint = 39;
    var down:uint = 40;



    var pickUpsArray:Array = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < alldisplay.numChildren; i++ )
    {
    if(alldisplay.getChildAt(i) is littleheart)
        {
    pickUpsArray.push(alldisplay.getChildAt(i));
        }  
    } 




    public function keylister(Display:MovieClip) 
    {
        alldisplay = new MovieClip();
        alldisplay = Display;
        alldisplay.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);
        alldisplay.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PickUpItems);


    }


    public function keyDownListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {


        if (e.keyCode == 37)
        {
            alldisplay.box_mc.x-=10;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            alldisplay.box_mc.y-=10;

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39)
        {
            alldisplay.box_mc.x+=10;

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            alldisplay.box_mc.y+=10;

        }
    }

    public function PickUpItems(e:Event):void
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < pickUpsArray.length; j++ )
        {
            if (alldisplay.box_mc.hitTestObject(pickUpsArray[j]))
            {
                alldisplay.removeChild(pickUpsArray[j]);
            }
        }
    }   


    }

   }
```

Comment: This looks like AS3 code. Asker is using AS2. Also things like `is littleheart` are going to cause errors like _"Undefined..."_ when they test. Best to fix Asker's own provided example code.